# Select and Display 'Suggested Tags' for All Posts Based on Related Questions (or other logic)

Tags: feature-request, tags, suggested-tags

### Tags should be suggested based on related questions

When you start typing a title, you get a bunch of related questions:

[image: Questions that may already have your answer]

When you click in the tag space however, you don't get any suggestions (save on meta):

[image: But what should I write here?!]

Now if you are working within a programming framework, this works great. You say, "My question is about [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)!" and you're off to the races. But what if you're on a site which doesn't fit in to default frameworks quite so nicely?

[image: Wait, what are tags?]

What the heck am I supposed to tag my question with?

1. What I'm currently doing (trying to get hired! errrr, [hiring-process](/questions/tagged/hiring-process))
2. My job title/source of my problem ([management](/questions/tagged/management))
3. My industry ([software-industry](/questions/tagged/software-industry))

(the suggestions for SO are a much more helpful [ios](/questions/tagged/ios), [.net](/questions/tagged/.net), [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby))

Can't we give the user a bit better context? We already have the related questions being displayed, and those questions have tags, right?

[image: Why yes they do]

Wouldn't it be absolutely awesome if you clicked in the tag box, and based on the related questions it gives you some suggestions even before typing based on the related questions to what you're asking?

You know, something like this:

[image: Impressive Useful Improvement]

This would make it easier for many of the not-so-easily-classified sites in the SE network to save time on tag cleanup and make it easier for users to find related questions, and to tag appropriately. It is such a simple and obvious improvement, it doesn't even need freehand red circles on it!

For reasons unknown, something similar to this is already implemented for Meta. For instance this is what it shows me for this post:

[image: Already Existing Feature Begging to be Rolled Out]

I have no idea how these are decided, but they aren't appearing on SE or on TW for me, only Meta SO.

## TL;DR

Suggest tags. I don't care if you ignore the methods or design suggested above. At the end of the day, suggest tags to new users and make SE just a wee bit more civilized.

Comment: This has my full support, even after using a site for so long, when I help re-tag a question I still have to sit and think about what tags I even have at my disposal