# Provide an easy way (or link) to browse to the tags page from the Ask a Question page

Tags: feature-request, tags, asking-questions

I joined a new site, and realized there's no easy way to "browse" the tags page from the Ask a Question page. The usual tag select box has its useful autocomplete, but it requires me to enter something before I can see anything. It's my first time on that site, and even a link to the tags page would help. (The links on the right panel were helpful.)

Comment: What about the “Tags” link in the left navigation? _“it requires me to enter something before I can see anything”_ — what is the desired user experience? Aren’t some tags [suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/206907/289905) after you type part of your question?

Comment: @user289905 I don't see any left navigation, sorry. I know what to type on a site like stackoverflow. I don't even know what kind of tags would exist on the new site. My suggestion was to include it either with the links on the right or near the tags search box.

Comment: [This link in the top left corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9cjh.png).

Comment: @user289905 that's what I was looking for thanks. I wonder how new users tag question. I'm sure they wouldn't know of that page while asking a question unless they've seen it before.

Comment: New users often mistag questions or provide no tags (beyond the required ones), just like you did here, and then other community members have to complete the tags, e.g. add a tag called [tag:tags].

Comment: @user289905 which is evidence that the search box doesn't help new users. It only makes sense for those already familiar with the tags on the site. I'd like the link to the tags page be made more prominent "while" opening a question, the same way we make links to "how to ask a good question" easily available. If tagging is important, there needs to be better guidance.

Comment: @galdin The popup which is opened when you click the menu icon user289905 posted a picture of is what is in the left-sidebar. The left-sidebar is shown by default to all users. At some point, you had to *choose* not to have the left-sidebar displayed to you. You might have made the choice by either a selection in your user preferences or by running an appropriate userscript. So, the link to the tags page is up-front and very visible by default. It's only your choice not to display the left-sidebar that makes it not as easy to find.

Comment: @Makyen I'm aware of that. The reason I posted here was so that community mods & the UX team at stack can see it. I'm very sure there's room for improvement wrt tagging *while creating a question*. Expecting users to look for tags on the sidebar/navbar IMO is not enough. The help icon at the bottom right is nice, but I didn't notice it.

Comment: This is probably *less* than an answer but as you noted the autocomplete requires you to type *something*, and you know you're asking about tags - so you'll probably start typing that. Once you start typing [a list of hints comes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS50E.jpg) and you can right-click (touch-hold) to read further; even clicking through as far as [the Tag FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18878/282094), where any often asked questions should be answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's easy!  Just click the blue help icon at the bottom right:

[image]

and click on "Use existing popular tags".  It'll take you straight to the [Tag page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags).

Credit to @user289905:  Alternatively, go here:

[image]

and click on "Tags".

Also, if you have the keyboard shortcuts script enabled in your preferences, you can use <kbd>Shift + ?</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd> for "go to", and then click <kbd>T</kbd> to go to the Tags page.  My favorite method.

Comment: Din't know this existed, thanks!

Comment: @galdin Much better way:  Keyboard shortcuts.